# Place logo and text in the same line

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create the header part of my page. In the header, I want to have an image (a logo) on the left side, and a "logged in as ..." on the right side of the same line.

The problem that I have is that the logo simply overrides the "logged in as" text, so only logo stays visible on the page, and there is no text.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="header">
    <span class="myLogo"/>

    <span class="user">
        Logged in as " target="_blank">${user}</a>
    </span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    .myLogo {
      display: inline;
      float: left;
      margin-left: 10px;
      margin-top: 30px;
      content:url("myLogo.png");
    }

    .user {
      text-align: right;
      white-space: nowrap;
      display: inline;
      float: left;
      margin-top: 20px;
      margin-right: 30px;
      font-size: large;
    }

    .header {
      display: inline-block;
}
```

How can I have my logo on the left side of the page, and my text on the right side of the page, but in the same line?

Comment: There are some missing tags and some self closing tags also used

Comment: If this is HTML (as opposed to XHTML) the construct `<span class="myLogo"/>` won't work the way you want to. That might be one of the causes of your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this CSS.

```
.myLogo {
          display: inline;
          float: left;
          margin-left: 10px;
          margin-top: 30px;
          content:url("myLogo.png");
        }

        .user {
          white-space: nowrap;
          display: inline;
          float: right;
          margin-top: 20px;
          margin-right: 30px;
          font-size: large;
        }

        .header {
          display: inline-block;
          width: 100%;clear:both;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should set

```
display: inline-block;
```

for both class or change class user to

```
float: right
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use content instead of an `<img>` tag?

Anyway, what I could suggest for you is to use flexbox:

```
.header{
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
}
.user{
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make 2 changes

1. remove inline block for `.header` class
2. Change `float:right` under `.user` class

```css
.myLogo {
      display: inline;
      float: left;
      margin-left: 10px;
      content:url("https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-NknV6HIVxKc/V06_WraBJEI/AAAAAAAAJWc/QwJMGxKHaywCIf2QHOLD-YwFQdn8VDaVgCLcB/s320/chelsea-logo.PNG");
      width:50px;
      height:50px;
    }

    .user {
      text-align: right;
      white-space: nowrap;
      display: inline;
      float: right;
      margin-right: 30px;
      font-size: large;
    }
```

```html
<div class="header">
    <span class="myLogo"></span>

    <span class="user">
        Logged in as <a target="_blank">hai</a>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: If I remove inline block, then even the logo is totally misplaced. It drops out of the div.

Comment: set the margin  to the logo class

Comment: remove margin-top from .mylogo clas

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method

HTML:

```
 <div>
<img class="myLogo" src = "myLogo.png"/>
</div>

<div class="user">
    Logged in as <a target="_blank">${user}</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
   .myLogo {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  height: 10px;
  width: auto;
}

.user {
  text-align: right;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  font-size: large;
}

.header {
  display: inline-block;
}
```